# How to read file with custom extension to textBox

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-extension

Is there any way to read file with custom extension to textBox? Is there any convertation to some supported formats? 
I need read file with custom extension, like `text.blahblahblah`.

Comment: What do you mean by `Is there any convertation to some supported formats?`

Comment: for example from to utf on some format, in what it can be readed.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Can you give more detailed examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to read file with custom extension to textBox?

Sure, just load the file text to the `TextBox` like:

```
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"Your input file path");
```

You can let the user choose the file using `OpenFileDialog` and specify a format accepted in the dialog filter.

If you want to also read `rtf` text then I think you need a `RichTextBox` instead of `TextBox` here so you can read `rtf` text probably using `richTextBox1.Rtf` string.

Comment: Maybe you have a wrong path here. what is the generated path? i.e what is the path string in this: `string path = "c:\\alps||" + project_name .....`

Comment: look question edit, path is good, but file formatž is unsupported. probably. Error is: "The given path format is unsupported"...

Comment: @FrewCen: I just notice your comment now.. the error `The given path's format is not supported` specify an error in the path, the `File.ReadAllText` should read the text regardless of the file format. what is the generated path if you use `string path = "C:\\Alps\\" + project_name + "\\" + treeView1.SelectedNode.Text";`